# How to get WSO2 developer studio work with source control system

Tags: wso2-integration-studio

I am using WSO2 developer studio to create ESB and DSS artifacts. I have created Maven multi module project and then created esb and dss artifacts.

The project layout looks similar to

```
Multi maven Parent Project
  ESBArtifacts
  DSSArtifacts
```

When I checkout from source control, ESB and DSS artifacts are created in root directory and not  keeping the parent project. Is there a way to preserve structure while using source control?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can checkout the project to a local folder and then import the project using 'Import WSO2 project' option. Make sure you add .project files to source control.

Comment: That is exactly how I am trying to do: 1. checkout the wso2 project from the source code 2. Import as wso2 project 3. in the project selection window, select all projects. This results in flat structure where multi maven parent project, esbartifacts and dssartifacts are at the same level.